# gitlab runners on fargate is not working as expected "sfdx command not found "

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, aws-fargate

I am runing a custom runner on aws fargate following this "https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/"

the custom docker is build from the salesforce/salesforcedx:7.207.3-full image with some extra packages and the needed gitlab runner driver and fargate driver
this is the docker file :

```
FROM salesforce/salesforcedx:7.207.3-full
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install pip -y

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Install https://github.com/krallin/tini - a very small 'init' process
# that helps processing signalls sent to the container properly.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
ARG TINI_VERSION=v0.19.0

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && \
    apt-get install -y curl

RUN curl -Lo /usr/local/bin/tini https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini-amd64 && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tini

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Install and configure sshd.
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service for reference.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server && \
    # Creating /run/sshd instead of /var/run/sshd, because in the Debian
    # image /var/run is a symlink to /run. Creating /var/run/sshd directory
    # as proposed in the Docker documentation linked above just doesn't
    # work.
    mkdir -p /run/sshd
#vite tsc

RUN apt-get -y install curl jq wget unzip
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install awscli --upgrade
RUN wget --quiet https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.3.7/terraform_1.3.7_linux_amd64.zip \
  && unzip terraform_1.3.7_linux_amd64.zip \
  && mv terraform /usr/bin \
  && rm terraform_1.3.7_linux_amd64.zip

RUN pip install colorama requests
RUN npm install sfdx-cli --global -force


EXPOSE 22

# ----------------------------------------
# Install GitLab CI required dependencies.
# ----------------------------------------
ARG GITLAB_RUNNER_VERSION=v12.9.0

RUN curl -Lo /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/${GITLAB_RUNNER_VERSION}/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-amd64 && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner && \
    # Test if the downloaded file was indeed a binary and not, for example,
    # an HTML page representing S3's internal server error message or something
    # like that.
    gitlab-runner --version

RUN apt-get install -y bash ca-certificates git git-lfs && \
    git lfs install --skip-repo

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Execute a startup script.
# https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data
# for reference.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

and this is the entrypoint.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh

# Create a folder to store user's SSH keys if it does not exist.
USER_SSH_KEYS_FOLDER=~/.ssh
[ ! -d ${USER_SSH_KEYS_FOLDER} ] && mkdir -p ${USER_SSH_KEYS_FOLDER}

# Copy contents from the `SSH_PUBLIC_KEY` environment variable
# to the `$USER_SSH_KEYS_FOLDER/authorized_keys` file.
# The environment variable must be set when the container starts.
echo ${SSH_PUBLIC_KEY} > ${USER_SSH_KEYS_FOLDER}/authorized_keys

# Clear the `SSH_PUBLIC_KEY` environment variable.
unset SSH_PUBLIC_KEY
# Start the SSH daemon
exec /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

the problem is that when i am runing the ci for a just a simple commend like
sfdx --version
i got an error that sfdx is not installed on the runner
if i will do the commend ls -l in the ci for the sfdx folder i can see its there and it has all the needed files
can you please help my understand what is the problem?

EDIT: when running the image locally everything is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the environment variables and dependencies are properly set up in the CI job running on AWS Fargate to make the sfdx command accessible. Reviewing the environment variables, permissions, and dependencies, as well as debugging the CI job, should help you identify and resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).